# R turn a list value into a dataframe with two columns

Tags: r

I have a list I created through a process that looks like this (so that I could pull from tidycensus):

```
dv_acs = c(
  hus          = "B25002_001", 
  husocc       = "B25002_002", 
  husvac       = "B17001_002"
)
```

I want to know if I can turn that into a data.frame. When I try to ask it to be a data.frame by:

```
out <- data.frame(dv_acs)
```

Then I get this:

```
           dv_acs
hus    B25002_001
husocc B25002_002
husvac B17001_002
```

Where the lefthand names replace what is normally 1:n but is not, in itself, a column of variables (data is noted as 3 obs of 1 variable).

Comment: Based on the subjects of the purported duplicates they all refer to lists but this question is about a named character vector even though it incorrectly calls it a list.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I kept that in mind while browsing, but they should all have answers that work for a vector as well as a list, including the ones in your answer. Feel free to edit if that's not the case for any of the links

Comment: If the answer to a different question happens to be an answer that works that does not make it a duplicate.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck one is specifically about a vector, the others are about unnested lists that will operate the same as a vector for this task. If you want to remove the list-specific ones that's fine

Answer (score 6):

**1)** This uses only base R.

```
stack(dv_acs)
##       values    ind
## 1 B25002_001    hus
## 2 B25002_002 husocc
## 3 B17001_002 husvac
```

**2)** We can also use `enframe`

```
library(tibble)

enframe(dv_acs)
## # A tibble: 3 × 2
##   name   value     
##  <chr>  <chr>     
##  1 hus    B25002_001
##  2 husocc B25002_002
##  3 husvac B17001_002
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a named character vector, not a `list` as understood in R. In any case, with the data you provided, one can create a data frame by doing:

```r
data.frame(name = names(dv_acs), dv_acs = unname(dv_acs))
#>     name     dv_acs
#> 1    hus B25002_001
#> 2 husocc B25002_002
#> 3 husvac B17001_002
```

Or

```r
tibble::rownames_to_column(as.data.frame(dv_acs), 'name')
#>     name     dv_acs
#> 1    hus B25002_001
#> 2 husocc B25002_002
#> 3 husvac B17001_002
```

Comment: Also `tibble::enframe(dv_acs)`